# Saved a copy of a webpage that uses webgl, but my hosted copy is getting a failure to load javascript resource error

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

Using Chrome, the [demo website](http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/visualizer-live.html) takes the input from your speakers/microphone and turns it into a live sound sonogram. I saved this website to my computer and hosted it on google drive, but the sonogram fails to show up.

The error in the console is: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (OK) and the error is in reference to the o3djs/shader.js file.

[Here](https://16f95935508d2a0520c1d02a8e97b01a1c0dbeff.googledrive.com/host/0B1BAuSBkA7Uvfkkwa3ptZXZvbDJ6UmFHemRGSWU2SWZSMDVYM0JFSHJ3N19wSTJLaHlEc2s/visualizer-live.html) is where I tried to host the webpage. The shader.js file seems to have loaded fine in the Sources window of the inspect element tool.

Comment: Can you post your code here, please?

Comment: Sometimes I see it fail to load shader.js which I agree doesn't make sense. But sometimes I see it fail to load other shader-related files which actually 404 on your server. For example,

common-vertex.shader,
waveform-fragment.shader,
sonogram-vertex.shader

Try downloading these from the source and adding them to your server.

Comment: Rob, how were you able to see that I was missing common-vertex.shader, etc?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out! I downloaded the shader files and figured out what folders they had to be in